# Broken link for kernel (nonexistent future version)

Tags: apt, kernel, dependencies, disk-usage, software-uninstall

My version (from `lsb_release -a`):

```
No LSB modules are available.  
Distributor ID: Ubuntu  
Description:    Ubuntu 14.10  
Release:        14.10  
Codename:       utopic
```

I want to make some room in my almost full boot partition so I typed:

```
dpkg -l | grep linux-image-
```

I checked my version with `uname -r` and got `3.16.0-29-generic`.

So I tried to remove `linux-image-3.16.0-24-generic` with:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove linux-image-3.16.0-24-generic
```

But when I do that I get an error about a broken dependency (not exactly the same message since my Ubuntu is in Spanish so I translated):

```
Next packages have unsatisfied dependencies:  
 linux-image-extra-3.16.0-24-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.16.0-24-generic but will not be installed  
 linux-image-extra-3.16.0-34-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.16.0-34-generic but will not be installed  
 linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.16.0-34-generic but will not be installed  
E: Unsatisfied dependencies. Try "apt-get -f install" without packages (or specify a solution).
```

**Note the future version of the dependency 3.16.0-34.**

So I tried:

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install
Next extra packages will be installed:  
  linux-image-3.16.0-34-generic  
Suggested packages:  
  fdutils linux-doc-3.16.0 linux-source-3.16.0 linux-tools  
next NEW packages will be installed:  
  linux-image-3.16.0-34-generic  
0 updated, 1 will be installed, 0 for deletion and 121 not updated.  
8 not installed at all or deleted.  
It will be need to download 0 B/16.2 MB in files.  
45.3 MB of additional disk space will be used after this operation.  
¿You wish to continue? [Y/n]  
(Reading database ... 374202 files or directories currently installed.)  
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-3.16.0-34-generic_3.16.0-34.45_amd64.deb ...
Done.  
Unpacking linux-image-3.16.0-34-generic (3.16.0-34.45) ...  
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.16.0-34-generic_3.16.0-34.45_amd64.deb (--unpack):  
  could no copy  extracted data from './boot/System.map-3.16.0-34-generic' to '/boot/System.map-3.16.0-34-generic.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream  
dpkg-deb: error: ths cpying subprocess was terminated by signal (Broken pipe)  
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .  
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.16.0-34-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-34-generic  
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.16.0-34-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-34-generic  
Errors found during processing  
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.16.0-34-generic_3.16.0-34.45_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

At this point I'm not sure if the problem is due to my almost full boot partition. I'm in a death lock here since I can not make room If I don´t install such broken dependency and I can not install it since my boot partition is almost full.

How can I get rid of previous kernels? I have done this other times without any problem. I tried with Synaptic but I kept getting the same results.

Comment: You say you're using `3.16.0-29-generic`, but you're trying to remove `3.16.0-24-generic`?

Comment: Wait. I think I get what you're saying. Don't run `apt-get autoremove 3.16.0-24-generic`, run `apt-get remove 3.16.0-24-generic`.

Comment: Zacharee1, I picked _3.16.0-24-generic_ since was the lowest version shown by _dpkg -l | grep linux-image-_ and all mess began

Comment: See my second comment. Try what's there.

Comment: Zacharee1, I tried _sudo apt-get remove 3.16.0-24-generic_ and got the same  
Next packages have unsatisfied dependencies:  
linux-image-extra-3.16.0-24-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.16.0-24-generic but will not be installed  
linux-image-extra-3.16.0-34-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.16.0-34-generic but will not be installed  
linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.16.0-34-generic but will not be installed  
E: Unsatisfied dependencies. Try "apt-get -f install" without packages (or specify a solution).

Comment: Try running these commands: `sudo dpkg --configure -a` `sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get autoclean`
`sudo apt-get clean`
`sudo dpkg --remove -force --force-remove-reinstreq tspc`

Comment: Zacharee1, some ran fine   
sudo dpkg --configure -a some messages about no space left and:   
Errors found during processing:  
 linux-image-extra-3.16.0-29-generic  
 linux-image-3.16.0-31-generic  
 linux-image-extra-3.16.0-34-generic  
 linux-image-generic  
 linux-image-extra-3.16.0-31-generic  
 linux-image-3.16.0-33-generic  
 linux-generic  
 linux-image-extra-3.16.0-33-generic sudo apt-get update _ok_
sudo apt-get autoclean _ok_
sudo apt-get clean _ok_
sudo dpkg --remove -force --force-remove-reinstreq tspc shows error: dpkg: error: conflicting actions -f (--field) and -r (--remove)

Comment: I think you may be better of leaving it alone or trying to do it from the Software Center.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo dpkg --remove  --force-remove-reinstreq linux-image-extra-3.16.0-24-generic*
```

allowed to remove first the extra package and then followed by:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove linux-image-3.16.0-24-generic
```

The package was removed. I could tell that `df -h` dropped /boot space from 98.5% to 85% and I used the same command with other packages.

Credit to *[Zacharee1](https://askubuntu.com/users/274320/zacharee1)* for showing the `--force-remove-reinstreq` option.